# Git differences are not updated with the latest changes from start point branch

Tags: git, github

I have a branch, lets call this `Y`, which was `git checkout -b` off a branch `X`. When I look at the diffs for latest commits in `Y` I see it compared to `X` at the commit from which `Y` was branched. I want the diffs to instead be compared to the latest commit `X`. How can I update this?

Comment: What do you mean by "look at the diffs for ... commits in `Y`"?  Specifically, what Git command(s) are you running?  (I ask because it's impossible to get a diff, in Git, without specifying at least *two* trees, but some Git commands figure out "the other tree" for you, and some require that you specify it yourself.)

Comment: Im looking at the diffs from Phabricator

Comment: So *you're* not using Git, or at least not directly?  Phabricator is running some Git command(s)?  What commands is it running?